# amazon connect sdk, search user by email

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying to obtain the amazon connect ID, if existing, that is related to an email using the aws sdk for node.js

Reading the following sdk:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Connect.html
or this one:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeUser.html

The closest thing I can see is describeUser, but that one requires the amazon connect id to retrieve the user data.

There are endpoints for search, but they dont seem to search users. It seems the only way is to get the entire user list via listUsers

Am I correct or is there a way to obtain a single user, given their email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS doesnt offer this functionality, best that can do is get the full list of users then query the user data for each id to obtain the emails and finally filter them yourself.